# Difference between Control.Invoke and Dispatcher.Invoke

Tags: c#, wpf, controls, dispatcher

In WPF whats the difference between Dispatcher.Invoke and Invoke called directly on an instance of a control. As far as i understand the dispatcher is responsible for handling messages for a thread, so does Control.Invoke go on to call Dispatcher.Invoke?

Answer (score 6):

As far as I'm aware, WPF controls don't *have* `Invoke` methods normally. There's nothing in [`System.Windows.Controls.Control`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.aspx), for example. Windows Forms controls have an [`Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30s4t80c.aspx) method, but then they don't have a dispatcher...

Answer (score -3):

in WPF, any of controls have **Invoke** Method but u can attach them.
in WinForms, You need to declare the Name of Control for example `Button1.Invoke`  or  `TextBox1.Invoke` to use **Cross Thread Calls**